# Updating View inside GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview, android-adapter

I have implemented an `ArrayAdapter` for customizing a `GridView`. The layout of each item is defined in xml code that produce something like this:

[image: layout GridView item]

In my Activity I have implemented the following code:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        adapter = new myArrayAdapter(this, articlesList);
        gridview.setAdapter(new myArrayAdapter(this, articlesList));     
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // here I want to change the text of the `TextView` in the right bottom corner to "CLICKED"
            }
        });
```

As explained in the commented section of the code, I simple want to update the TextView in the right bottom corner, writing in it the text "CLICKED".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `View` parameter to `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` `onItemClick()` is the view that was clicked. In your case it will be the item root `RelativeLayout`. Call `findViewById()` on it or use the ViewHolder pattern to obtain a reference to the `TextView` you want to update and just update it.

Also note that when the views are recycled i.e. your adapter's `getView()` is called with a non-null `convertView`, you need to reset the `TextView` to its default state.

Comment: Thank you @laalto Yes, I'm using recycling views, but if I reset the TextView to default value, I lost the text "CLICKED" in my TextView

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to set a TextView to "Clicked", if all you want to do is give the user the feedback that they have checked an item. An alternative might be to do the following. Note, this method will also help you set a textview to "clicked" if you still need to.

To check an item I would extend your `RelativeLayout` as follows:

```
public class CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {
        android.R.attr.state_checked
    };

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (mChecked != checked) {
            mChecked = checked;
            refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call `parent.setItemChecked(position,true);` in `onItemClick` which will actually set the item as checked within the `AdapterView`.

Doing this will then allow you to set a background selector on the extended `RelativeLayout` and the items will perform selected, pressed, checked etc actions. However, you don't need to use a background selector.

There is more, you can alway see whether the view is checked with `gridview.getCheckedItemPosition()` which you may find useful if you want to actually set the textview to "Clicked".

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        parent.setItemChecked(position,true);
        yourAdapter.ViewHolder vh = (yourAdapter.ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        vh.textView.setText("Clicked");
    }
});
```

In your adapter you can hold a reference to you extended relative layout in your static ViewHolder class and if checked (e.g. `holder.extendedrelativeLayout.isChecked()`) then make sure you set the textView to "Clicked".

Answer (score 0):

try `gridView.invalidateViews();` it automatically calls getView() method of the adapter and updates the view.